# What's the earliest citation for "you can hear the dice rolling in the background" about a piece of fantasy fiction?

Tags: fantasy-genre

The earliest I remember hearing this comment was about Dragonlance, which began to be published in 1984.  There was earlier RPG-influenced fiction, though, as far back as Norton's *Quag Keep* (1978).  Do we know the origin of the phrase?

Comment: I think the earliest I read it was in a review of E. Gary Gygax's first novel, *Saga of Old City*.  That came out in 1985, after the first *Dragonlance* books proved that novels based on AD&D could be very successful.  I'm not sure where I would have read the review though.

Comment: Not necessarily the same thing, but in Terry Pratchett's *The Colour of Magic* (1983) there actually *were* dice rolling in the background, as the gods of Discworld played a game of D&D over the characters' fates.  From time to time, just before something particularly unexpected happened, the characters would look up and wonder what that funny noise was that sounded like dice.

Comment: The Dragonlance series is the earliest popular novel I'm aware of. The Record of Lodoss War novels were also based on a campaign in 1986.

This isn't specifically RPG influenced but tangentially related - Philip Dick used the I-Ching to make decisions for The Man in the High Castle, which was in 1962. From an interview, he said: "I used it in The Man in the High Castle because a number of characters used it. In each case when they asked a question, I threw the coins and wrote the hexagram lines they got. That governed the direction of the book." Literal coins being flipped in the background!

Comment: My guess is *Quag Keep*: this was released as AD&D 1st edition was being released… OD&D had existed for a few years at that point, but was—in the Gygax, Arnesson, &Co circles more or less the genesis of dice-driven RPGs. There may have been some previous "dice in the background" metaphors for *fate*, but they are unlikely to be RPG-related.